# what is necessary to build cap file uses proprietary package except *.exp file?

Tags: javacard

i have java card which supports some proprietary classes, say "ClassFoo" in package "packagename.foo". I have documentation for these classes and "foo.exp" file. But as i undestand it is neccessary something else to build cap file because without it compiler finds errors like uknown import package and unknown class. Right? What is it?

Comment: how are you compiling? which tools? what is the error message?

Comment: @PaulBastian i compile like something that `javac -classpath JAVACARD_SDK_PATH\bin\lib\api.jar SRC_PATH\test.java`. Errors are simple  `package packagename.foo does not exist` and `cannot find symbol ClassFoo`.

Comment: You should have a `.jar` for this extension package as well and add it to the compiler `-classpath` (like the `api.jar` you are already using). Or if you have a bunch of `.class` files you add their toplevel directory (like in standard java). This way it _should_ compile. For converting to `.cap` you need the `.exp` file(s).

Comment: @vlp I suggest that you create an answer out of your comment.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `.exp` file is used by the offcard Java Card converter. The converter converts standard Java classes to the `.cap` files which can be uploaded to the Java Card implementation (usually through Global Platform).

To generate these class files you first need to compile the classes. For this the usual Java linker needs to link against the interface of the external classes. So vlp is correct that you need `.class` files to compile against. Usually those classes are packaged into a `.jar` file.

---

Now the actual implementation of these classes usually only runs on a Java Card runtime. The linking is performed using the .exp file. So the contents of the actual classes is not important during linking, and they are not used during execution either (unless you are running on [jCardSim](https://jcardsim.org/) of course).

So it's quite often that you get a .jar that contains all the public interfaces, classes and methods but doesn't contain any implementation (other than `return null` or `return 0` where required).

It may even be possible to generate your own stub and link against that if you know the full interface (from the Java Doc).